# Aliases in Haskell/GHCI

Tags: haskell, terminal, alias, ghci

Is it possible to set aliases in the ghci.conf file?

For example I have `alias sbh='cd Desktop/Sandbox/Haskell'` in bash.bashrc which lets me quickly jump to the specified folder.  Is the same thing possible in ghci by putting an alias in the ghci.conf file?

I already have a few commands in ghci.conf but I would like to have multiple aliases set up to jump to folder locations without having to use `:cd home/sandbox/foo/bar` all of the time. I cant find anything on google so either its never been considered before or am just missing something very simple.

Comment: According to the manual (https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.2/html/users_guide/ghci-dot-files.html), commands in the .ghci file are executed line by line. So I suppose unless you needs can be expressed by any of the commands listed when typing ':help' i ghci, it is probably not possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`:def` command](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ghci-commands.html) can do this:

```
:def sbh const $ return ":cd Desktop/Sandbox/Haskell"
```

As you can see it is a little more complicated than just giving a substitution string: It takes a Haskell function of type `String -> IO String` which the newly defined command applies to its argument string to calculate new commands to run.

Then in GHCI `:sbh` to invoke.

Comment: exactly what I wanted, thanks. I've made a small edit to the answer for anybody who is new to GHCI/Haskell to avoid them making the same error I did (tying sbh into GHCI rather than :sbh).

Comment: Nice description. A function of type `String -> IO String` feels much more comfortable to me than a substitution. Maybe after all these years I'm healed from my awk hacking days.

Answer (score 3):

GHCI macros should give you what you're looking for. See: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/ghci-commands.html as a reference.

Search for "macros" (or :def, which is the command to define macros). You can put these in the ghci.conf file.

For example (from the same URL indicated above):

`Prelude> let mycd d = Directory.setCurrentDirectory d >> return ""
Prelude> :def mycd mycd
Prelude> :mycd ..`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Possible not exactly what you need, but in case the quick-jumping function suffices try this as a first fix (invoked by `:sbh`):

```
:def sbh (\arg -> return ("System.Directory.setCurrentDirectory \"Desktop/Sandbox/Haskell\""))
```

Your later solution might make use of the `arg` reference like in:

```
:def sbh (\arg -> return ("System.Directory.setCurrentDirectory " ++ "\"" ++ args ++ "\""))
```

Invoke the latter which by `:sbh Desktop/Sandbox/Haskell` then.