# How to reload a file in ghci without modifying the source code?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I am using ghc-8.10.2. When I compile a source file (which contains many top bindings and a main function, without a `module` declaration) into a *executable*, then type `ghci` to use the interpreter of ghc, load the source file with the `:load filename` command. I found that only the `main` top-binding is visible in ghci environment, other top bindings can be refereed unless I have made some meaningless modification to the source file, and reload it, I have tried to reload the file without making changes in the source file, even with the `:reload` command, but it doesn't work, so I want to ask if there is a command to force reload a module at any time.

Comment: Possibly `:set -fno-object-code` and then `:reload`? If not, there's probably a hack to make it look in the wrong place for object code.

Comment: Another thing to try is `:m *Main` (or whatever is the name of the module in `filename`). The key bit there is the `*`.

Comment: `:reload` a module with filename just doesn't work.

Comment: `:set -fno-object-code` will output the message **Some flags have not been recognized: -fno-object-code**, and I have tried  `:set -fbyte-code` before, it's recognized but is invalid.

Comment: I have followed ghci's hint message: **module 'Main' is not interpreted; try ':add *Main' first** to try `:add *Main`, but it tell me that ```<no location info>: error:
    module ��main:Main�� is defined in multiple files: parser.hs
                                                     parser.hs
Failed, one module loaded.```

Comment: You could also hack it by making an [alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381664/aliases-in-haskell-ghci) that `:!touch`es the file and then `:reload`s it.

Answer (score 0):

`:r` should be it, instead of `:reload` that other people seem to have used.

Comment: `:r` is the same as `:reload`. (More precisely, all the colon-commands can be shortened arbitrarily, as long as it's still unambiguous, and even if it's ambiguous it'll pick the first alphabetic match. Therefore, `:r` and `:re` and `:rel` and `:relo` and `:reloa` and `:reload` are all the same.)

Answer (score 0):

Up to the [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf)

> An abbreviated form of module, consisting only of the module body, is permitted. If this is used, the header is assumed to be ‘module Main(main) where’.

Meaning that if you don't use a `module` declaration, by default you only export the `main` function from it. That's why you can only load such function. If you want to avoid this start your file with

```
module Main where
...
```