# Haskell - Variable not in scope: -error for function

Tags: haskell, ghci

I've only been learning Haskell for a week or so, and am currently trying to write a function which  returns 0 if the second argument is smaller than the first, and returns the product of the range between the two arguments otherwise:

```
rangeProduct :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> a
rangeProduct x y
  | y < x = 0 
  | otherwise = product [x..y]
```

When I compile it in ghci (I'm using VSC, if that matters) it returns the following error:
Variable not in scope: rangeProduct :: t0 -> t1 -> t

The "variable not in scope" part is pretty self explanatory, but is it saying the function declaration itself isn't in scope?
I've been going a bit crazy trying to figure this out, any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Are you literally copy-pasting this into an interactive GHCI prompt or saving it to a file and then doing `:l filename.hs`? If it's the former, you need to prefix the declaration with `let` since the interactive prompt runs in a sort of hybrid declaration mode.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo the latter- saving it and doing ```:l filename.hs```

Comment: Hm... unfortunately, your function works perfectly well for me. Have you ruled out the usual suspects? Made sure you're in the right folder, that you've saved the file, that you're working with the most current version of the file, etc., etc.? I only ask because I can't seem to reproduce the behavior you're describing. If you made a change to the file after doing the `:l filename.hs` instruction, then you have to use `:r` to reload previously loaded files.

Comment: your function is right. Do you have any extra configuration?

Comment: When you say "compile it in ghci" what do you mean? A more precise question. Do you get the error when running `:l filename.hs` or when running `rangeProduct 3 0` after loading the file?? It can be a duplicated of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66734442/how-to-reload-a-file-in-ghci-without-modifying-the-source-code)